# How to update wp-config file in Docker

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to change our blogs from Wordpress to inside a docker container, so that we can move around it easily. I wrote a docker-compose file for the purpose and it ran smoothly the first time. But I made some mistakes on configs and missed to write the `HOME` and `SITEURL` on the docker-compose file in the beginning. Now, I can't seem to change the `wp-config.php`. according to Wordpress, it can't be updated from the entrypoint script once it's already been written. I tried a bunch of other scenarios:

1. I tried to use `docker exec` command to update the wp-config.php file. bash does not have vim/nano there.
2. I deleted all the containers and volumes and images, but still, it doesn't change anything. I downed and re-uploaded the compose file many times, but nothing is changing.

Here's a snippet of my compose file. What should I do now? [I need to change the home and siteurl because the Wordpress will be served from a different server.]

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes:
      - mysql_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA=
          define('WP_HOME','http://dev.insurance.kothay.com/');
          define('WP_SITEURL','http://dev.insurance.kothay.com/');
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network
  
volumes:
  wordpress_data:
  mysql_db_data:
  
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Docker message:

```
wordpress    | WARNING: environment variable "WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA" is set, but "wp-config.php" already exists
wordpress    |   The contents of this variable will _not_ be inserted into the existing "wp-config.php" file.
wordpress    |   (see https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/333 for more details)
w
```

Let me know what I can do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wordpress    | WARNING: environment variable "WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA" is set, but "wp-config.php" already exists
wordpress    |   The contents of this variable will _not_ be inserted into the existing "wp-config.php" file.
wordpress    |   (see https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/333 for more details)
```

This is a sign you are restarting wordpress with an already initialized volume. If you don't need the existing data in wordpress, you could delete the volume, restarting from scratch, where these variables would then be used:

```
docker volume rm ${project}_wordpress_data
```

Where project is likely your current directory name. You can also run `docker volume ls` to find the volume name.

To edit the existing file in a volume, you can start a temporary container with vim to edit the file:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v ${project}_wordpress_data:/vol -w /vol \
  busybox /bin/sh
```

Comment: I turned down the docker. and ran the `rm`command, but I got the following message: `Error response from daemon: remove shodai-blog-dockerized_wordpress_data: volume is in use - [43ade39ba3a495154fefd9ccd79b2c2c53765482e2c7c4d2859b7051383839ae]`


I don't have any container up.

Comment: @O_o check for non-running containers. `docker ps -a`